# Should MyApp.vshost.exe be distributed with MyApp.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

When building my C# .NET project, a 'MyApp.vshost.exe' file was placed in the release bin with 'MyApp.exe' under Visual Studio 2010. When distributing 'MyApp.exe' should I package the 'MyApp.vshost.exe' with it as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the [hosting process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is a feature that improves debugging scenarios only. Your customers should have no need for it at all.

Answer (score 2):

No.

That file is only needed to allow your application run from within Visual Studio. It stands for **V***isual***S***tudio***HOST**.

Answer (score 1):

No. This application is used in debugging only. [Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

No.

And when creating a setup.exe you don't even have to know that.

Just select "Primary output" and the setup-generator will know what to do.